# Updating the actionbar as user navigates app

Tags: android

In my Android app, I provide a navigation menu via a navigation drawer. I would like the actionbar to have different icons based upon where they have navigated to. I see two approaches to this. Either I just show/hide actionbar buttons (and other controls) as needed as the user navigates the app, or, I create a completely new actionbar for each screen where they navigate to and replace the existing actionbar. The latter approach has one drawback in that I might end up repeating some buttons from other actionbars.

Not sure if there are any other issues I should be concerned about with either solution. Any suggestions on the approach I might take?

Comment: can you post an image what and where would you like to put the icon

Comment: No. There is no need to. It's a general question that doesn't require any image.

Comment: Are you using separate activities or one single activity in which you swap fragments upon navigation?

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `getActionBar().setIcon(int resId);` and set the parameter to your resource drawable

for example

```
if(x == 1) {
    getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icone1);
} else if (x == 2) {
    getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icone2);
} else if (x == 3) {
    getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icone3);
}else if ...
```

or you can call `getSupportActionBar()` if you want to use the support library

Comment: Don't see what this has to do with my question. The question is about a design pattern, not how to set icons.

Answer (score -2):

You do not create the `ActionBar`, it is provided by the system. Each activity is given an `ActionBar` as long as the theme for that activity extends one of the existing themes that contain an `ActionBar` (e.g. Holo, Holo.Light, and Holo.Light.DarkActionBar) and doesn't specify that it contains no action bar.

The way to achieve what you want by defining the appropriate menu XML files for your activities and fragments and properly overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu` in both. Also note for Fragments that you need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` inside of `onCreate()`.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

Comment: You completely misunderstood my question. I am totally familiar with creating actionbars and know how place controls on it. My question is about a design pattern. Add all the controls and simply make them visible or invisible based upon the screen being shown, or, replace the entire actionbar with all the buttons for each screen.

Comment: There is no "design pattern". You either navigate to a new activity or you replace fragments in your existing activity. Either way, which action items appear on the `ActionBar` are based on your menu XML files for the Activity you are in and the Fragments that are attached and visible. Which approach you want is entirely up to you depending on your app and your needs.

Comment: I realize the approach is up to me. But it is still a design pattern and clearly has advantages/disadvantages either way. I was looking for someone who has already done it either way and can advise what to take into consideration.